# Passing props to router component in react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-router-v4

For example:

```
import SomeComponent...

<Router>
    <Route path='/' component={SomeComponent} />
</Router>
```

How do I pass something to `SomeComponent` so that I can access it in the component through `this.props.xxx` ?

Comment: well, you use the `render` property (and not the `component` property) on the `<Route` tag, or you use something like redux and create a connnected component, or use a HOC to inject some data that should always be available, plenty of choices ;)

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105 check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Router>
    <Route path='/' component={(props) => 
        (<SomeComponent value={this.state.value} {...props} )/>} />
</Router>
```

Note, you need to pass `...props` if you want to access route properties in the component (such as match, location or history like in `this.props.history` in the component's code).

---

Update:

For performance reasons, it might be better to use `render` in this case, like in:

```
 <Router>
        <Route path='/' render={(props) => 
            (<SomeComponent value={this.state.value} {...props} )/>} />
    </Router>
```

As per [react docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component):

> When you use component (instead of render or children) the
>   router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   component attribute, you would create a new component every render.
>   This results in the existing component unmounting and the new
>   component mounting instead of just updating the existing component.
>   When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or
>   the children prop (below).